# How to rescue files from a HDD using a bootable USB?

Tags: login, live-usb, data-recovery, users, rescue-mode

I am new to Ubuntu.
My computer doesn't start and I need to rescue some files from it.
I tried to boot from a live USB and did it successfully. I reached the HDD but the folders are locked (I can see the pictures because there are an "x" on them and it doesn't open) and other folders seems to be empty (I know there are archives in it).
I tried to run commands as su ando sudo but I couldn't run as the original user to have full access to the archives.
In the terminal says the user is ubuntu@ubuntu.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the use of "pastes", @LucasMP can you clarify what you mean or maybe someone else can edit if there is a better word.  It sounds like you live-booted successfully and maybe mounted the hard drive in the computer with the problem. Is that true?

Comment: Hello Denis. My computer doesn't start. I successfully booted using a live USB. I reached the HDD of the computer but the pastes/folders are either empty or the pictures in it are not opening because it has an "x" in it. I tried moving them to another usb but it only goes empty folders.

Comment: start the filemanager with `sudo -H nautilus` then you have access to your files.

Comment: Thanks. It worked well. I got access to all the archives.